# [UWP][C++/CX] Cannot access XAML UI from codebehind

Tags: c++-cli, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

C++:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"

using namespace Testing;

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;

MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


void Testing::MainPage::Page_SizeChanged(Platform::Object^ sender,Windows::UI::Xaml::SizeChangedEventArgs^ e)
{
    SplitPane->isPaneOpen = !SplitPane->isPaneOpen; //LEGAL
}
void test() 
{
    SplitPane->isPaneOpen = !SplitPane->isPaneOpen; //NOT LEGAL
}
```

XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="Testing.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Testing"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
SizeChanged="Page_SizeChanged">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <SplitView Name="SplitPane">
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

So my question is why i cant use a reference or rather find the reference of the SplitView in my function? and is there a solution?
I find it a bit ugly to pass SplitPane as parameter
P.S. in C# test() is completely legal

Comment: C++ and C++/CLI are not the same thing. I have updated the tag but please be mindful of how you tag your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the private fields of a `MainPage`, `test()` must be a method of the `MainPage` class.

In `MainPage.xaml.h`:

```
public ref class MainPage sealed
{
public:
    MainPage();
    void test();
};
```

In `MainPage.xaml.cpp`:

```
void MainPage::test() 
{
    SplitPane->IsPaneOpen = !SplitPane->IsPaneOpen; // LEGAL
}
```